# MainWindow.xib is just a black screen

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

I'm trying to test the following code : http://github.com/mobilemelting/nvpolyline. When I run the app, all I get is a black screen. There are only two View Controllers, MainWindow.xib and NVMapViewController.xib.

See my settings for MainWindow.xib in the attached image.

What am I missing ?

Regards,
Stephen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clone the project, and compile it against the 4.x SDK, it should work - I've just tested it, and it compiles and runs just fine.

If you are getting this problem after changing something, analyse your changes, and work backwards to find out where you introduced the problem.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I didn't see the download option on Github. I was cutting and pasting. Just downloaded it not and it works fine.